# Cyclic irreducible subgroups of $GL(2,p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, general-linear-group

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Is it possible to have an *cyclic* irreducible subgroup of $GL(2,p)$ of order $q^n$, say, with $n>0$ and some prime $q$, such that some proper subgroup is still irreducible?

Comment: Please explain your terminologies. What is an "irreducible cyclic subgroup"? It sounds to me like a simple cyclic subgroup, but then it must have prime order. And what is $\operatorname{GL}(2,p)$? Is it $\operatorname{GL}(2, \Bbb F_p)$?

Comment: @WhatsUp I've changed the order of the words. I meant an irreducible subgroup which is also a cyclic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can happen. For example ${\rm GL}(2,17)$ has an irreducible cyclic subgroup of order $9$, and its subgroup of order $3$ is also irreducible.

In fact I think it always happens. Given $q^n$ with $q$ and odd prime and $q>1$, choose any prime $p$ with $q^n$ dividing $p+1$. Then ${\rm GL}(2,p)$ has an irreducible cyclic subgroup of order $q^n$ and all of its nontrivial subgroups are also irreducible, because $q$ cannot divide $p-1$.